# How to address an object from a json array

Tags: c#, json.net

Using the JSON library, I've imported an array of objects:

```
dynamic serviceList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(listString)
```

I've got an array of json objects, each has the property "name".

```
[
   {
      "name":"abcd",
      "properties":{
         "type":"1234"
      }
   },
   {
      "name":"xyz",
      "properties":{
         "type":"aaaa"
      }
   }
]
```

How do I address just the object "abcd"?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to make your deserialization towards a defined type? Or why you are not just using JObject / JToken?

Comment: None as such, that's just the reference code I've been given from Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your json Array using Newtonsoft.Json `JArray.Parse()` function.

Use `FirstOrDefault()` to get record where name is "abcd"

```
string listString = @"[{'name': 'abcd','properties': {'type': '1234'}},{'name': 'xyz', 'properties': { 'type': 'aaaa'}}]";
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(listString);

//FirstOrDefault to get first record which satisfy the condition
var result = jArray.FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x["name"] == "abcd");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "abcd",
  "properties": {
    "type": "1234"
  }
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t14YOq)

Answer (score 0):

This will get the value for you as a JObject, from which you can access the contained values:

```cs
var serviceList = JArray.Parse(listString);
var target = serviceList.Single(s => s["name"].ToString() == "abcd");
if (target != null)
{
    var type = target["properties"]["type"];
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to solve the problem is create a static Object

```
Public Obj1 {

public string name {get;set;}
public Properties properties {get;set;}

}

Public Properties {

public string type {get;set;}

}
```

Then you can deserialize the JSON into a `List<Obj1>`, in this way you can iterate your list and find the "name":"abcd" Object. `var myobj = mylist.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.name == "abcd")`

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < serviceList.Count; i++)
  {
      if (serviceList[i].name == "abc")
      {
         DoSomethingWith(serviceList[i];
         break;
      }
  }
```

Edit: didn't see that you wanted the "abc" element, so modified the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamic to do pretty much anything you would like it to do, so nothing would stop you from evaluating your result in the following way:

```
dynamic selectionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( json );

foreach (var item in selectionList) {
    if ( string.Equals( (string)item.name, "abcd", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) {
        Console.WriteLine( item );
    }
}
```

This would work as per your original request, but I think you are making it a lot harder on yourself than need be :)

To see how this works, you could check this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OkwwGg)

I would probably create a class based on the spec, but I am assuming that properties is a dynamic list of properties and their values, meaning you would still end up with a `Dictionary<string, object>` in the end